Best way to create a MTLTexture from a CVPixelBuffer for real-time processing
I'm trying to process video frames in real-time using AVFoundation's AVCaptureDevice but having trouble getting a "clean" MTLTexture from a CVPixelBuffer. AVPlayer buffers do not seem to have the same problem. I want to compute a histogram and a video waveform scope using Metal shaders for efficiency.
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput generates a CVPixelBuffer with a certain pixel format (usually kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA or kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8). I've tried a couple of different ways of creating a MTLTexture from it:

Use CIRenderDestination

// Create InputTexture to hold frame
let inputTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba32Float, width: inputImageWidth, height: inputImageHeight, mipmapped: false)
inputTextureDescriptor.usage = [.shaderRead, .shaderWrite]
inputTextureDescriptor.textureType = .type2D
inputTexture = device!.makeTexture(descriptor: inputTextureDescriptor)

// Create InputTexture from CVPixelBuffer
let destination = CIRenderDestination(mtlTexture: inputTexture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer)
try! context!.startTask(toRender: inputImage, from: inputImage.extent, to: destination, at: .zero)


Use CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

var newTexture: CVMetalTexture?
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache!, inputBuffer!, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &newTexture)
let inputTexture: MTLTexture! = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(newTexture!)

Option 1 seems to handle pixel format conversions into a .rgba32Float MTLTexture no problem. Option 2 requires much more attention to matching the CVPixelBuffer pixel format to the MTLTexture picture format, otherwise the texture creation fails.
The problem I'm having is that no matter which method I use, the resulting MTLTexture shows some "notching" or aliasing in the histogram. This is not a problem when I create metal textures using the same methods from CVPixelBuffers that come from a video file using AVPlayer.
This histogram is from Xcode's MTLTexture Quick Look viewer when using AVCaptureDevice. You can see the serrated curve in all 3 channels.

This is a histogram of a MTLTexture created from a frame coming from AVPlayer. Notice how smooth the curves are in this case.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm creating the MTLTexture or if I'm missing something else?

Update: adding more information about how I get the textures

From AVCaptureVideoDataOutput:

// VideoOutput is configured like this
videoOutput.videoSettings =
                    [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
...
// And the buffer is retrieved from the callback like this:
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection {
  if let buffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.model?.currentBuffer = buffer
    }
  }
}
...
// Later I create a CIImage using the constructor
var ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)

The resulting CVPixelBuffer description is:
<CVPixelBuffer 0x600003bfd760 width=1920 height=1080 bytesPerRow=7680 pixelFormat=BGRA iosurface=0x600000e434d0 surfaceid=2496 attributes={
    Height = 1080;
    IOSurfaceProperties =     {
        IOSurfacePurgeWhenNotInUse = 1;
    };
    PixelFormatType = 1111970369;
    Width = 1920;
} propagatedAttachments={
    AlphaChannelIsOpaque = 1;
    CGColorSpace = "<CGColorSpace 0x600002892940> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; HDTV)";
    CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField = TopLeft;
    CVImageBufferColorPrimaries = "ITU_R_709_2";
    CVImageBufferTransferFunction = "ITU_R_709_2";
    CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix = "ITU_R_709_2";
    MetadataDictionary =     {
        AEAverage = 130;
        AELimitsReached = 0;
        AETarget = 122;
        AGC = 2048;
        ConversionGain = 13018;
        DetectedFacesArray =         (
                        {
                AnfdModality = 1;
                AngleInfoRoll = 0;
                AngleInfoYaw = 0;
                ConfidenceLevel = 501;
                EyeCoveringConfidenceLevel = 0;
                FaceID = 1;
                FaceMaskConfidenceLevel = 0;
                Modality = 0;
                Rect =                 {
                    Height = "0.387962962962963";
                    Width = "0.2182291666666667";
                    X = "0.4666666666666667";
                    Y = "0.6935185185185185";
                };
                Timestamp = 7105498774941;
            }
        );
        ExposureBias = 0;
        Fnumber = 2;
        FocalLenIn35mmFilm = "27.71519491471626";
        FocalLength = "1.27";
        LuxLevel = 15;
        NormalizedSNR = "9.941646800333446";
        RawSensorHeight = 1080;
        RawSensorWidth = 1920;
        "ReadNoise_1x" = 203862;
        "ReadNoise_8x" = 98618;
        SNR = "9.941646800333446";
        TotalSensorCropRect =         {
            Height = 1080;
            Width = 1920;
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        };
        ispDGain = 1780;
        ispDGainRangeExpansionFactor = "1.015625";
        sensorDGain = 256;
    };
} nonPropagatedAttachments={
}>

And the resulting MTLTexture:
<CaptureMTLTexture: 0x60000173da40> -> <AGXG13XFamilyTexture: 0x15786ba10>
    label = input_texture 
    textureType = MTLTextureType2D 
    pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA32Float 
    width = 1920 
    height = 1080 
    depth = 1 
    arrayLength = 1 
    mipmapLevelCount = 1 
    sampleCount = 1 
    cpuCacheMode = MTLCPUCacheModeDefaultCache 
    storageMode = MTLStorageModeManaged 
    hazardTrackingMode = MTLHazardTrackingModeTracked 
    resourceOptions = MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache MTLResourceStorageModeManaged MTLResourceHazardTrackingModeTracked  
    usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite 
    shareable = 0 
    framebufferOnly = 0 
    purgeableState = MTLPurgeableStateNonVolatile 
    swizzle = [MTLTextureSwizzleRed, MTLTextureSwizzleGreen, MTLTextureSwizzleBlue, MTLTextureSwizzleAlpha] 
    isCompressed = 0 
    parentTexture = <null> 
    parentRelativeLevel = 0 
    parentRelativeSlice = 0 
    buffer = <null> 
    bufferOffset = 0 
    bufferBytesPerRow = 0 
    iosurface = 0x0 
    iosurfacePlane = 0 
    allowGPUOptimizedContents = YES


Using AVPlayer

// Is configured like this

playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoSourceURL)
let settings = [ String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat ]
videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: settings)
...
// And the buffer retrieved using DisplayLink
if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime) {
  var presentationItemTime = CMTime.zero
  let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: &presentationItemTime)!
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.model!.currentBuffer = pixelBuffer
  }
}

With a resulting CVPixelBuffer description:
<CVPixelBuffer 0x60000211c160 width=1920 height=1080 bytesPerRow=30720 pixelFormat=RGfA iosurface=0x6000014237a0 poolName=decode_1 surfaceid=484 attributes={
    PixelFormatDescription =     {
        BitsPerBlock = 128;
        BitsPerComponent = 32;
        BlackBlock = {length = 16, bytes = 0x0000000000000000000000000000803f};
        CGBitmapContextCompatibility = 1;
        CGBitmapInfo = 8451;
        CGImageCompatibility = 1;
        ComponentRange = FullRange;
        ContainsAlpha = 1;
        ContainsGrayscale = 0;
        ContainsRGB = 1;
        ContainsYCbCr = 0;
        FillExtendedPixelsCallback = {length = 24, bytes = 0x0000000000000000b0304989010000000000000000000000};
        IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility = 1;
        IOSurfaceOpenGLTextureCompatibility = 1;
        OpenGLCompatibility = 1;
        OpenGLFormat = 6408;
        OpenGLInternalFormat = 6408;
        OpenGLTextureCacheCompatibility = 1;
        OpenGLType = 5126;
        PixelFormat = 1380410945;
    };
} propagatedAttachments={
    CGColorSpace = "<CGColorSpace 0x6000032a6a60> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Composite NTSC)";
    CVFieldCount = 1;
    CVImageBufferColorPrimaries = "SMPTE_C";
    CVImageBufferTransferFunction = "ITU_R_709_2";
    CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix = "ITU_R_601_4";
    "ProResHW_CheckValue" = 59911245;
    QTMovieTime =     {
        TimeScale = 30000;
        TimeValue = 62500;
    };
} nonPropagatedAttachments={
}>

And MTLTexture:
<CaptureMTLTexture: 0x600000cf5200> -> <AGXG13XFamilyTexture: 0x1496217b0>
    label = input_texture 
    textureType = MTLTextureType2D 
    pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA32Float 
    width = 1920 
    height = 1080 
    depth = 1 
    arrayLength = 1 
    mipmapLevelCount = 1 
    sampleCount = 1 
    cpuCacheMode = MTLCPUCacheModeDefaultCache 
    storageMode = MTLStorageModeManaged 
    hazardTrackingMode = MTLHazardTrackingModeTracked 
    resourceOptions = MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache MTLResourceStorageModeManaged MTLResourceHazardTrackingModeTracked  
    usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite 
    shareable = 0 
    framebufferOnly = 0 
    purgeableState = MTLPurgeableStateNonVolatile 
    swizzle = [MTLTextureSwizzleRed, MTLTextureSwizzleGreen, MTLTextureSwizzleBlue, MTLTextureSwizzleAlpha] 
    isCompressed = 0 
    parentTexture = <null> 
    parentRelativeLevel = 0 
    parentRelativeSlice = 0 
    buffer = <null> 
    bufferOffset = 0 
    bufferBytesPerRow = 0 
    iosurface = 0x0 
    iosurfacePlane = 0 
    allowGPUOptimizedContents = YES


Update 2: Adding a close-up of the MTLTexture pixels that shows the issue.
This image of a MTLTexture with a pixel format of kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat shows how several different pixels (some clustered, some not) have the exact same float values. The system seems to be forcing the pixels into discreet buckets. And it doesn't look like compression macro blocking, banding, or chroma sub-sampling artifacts.


Update 3: Addition pixel format tests
I also configured the video capture device to use kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange (the 422 option is not supported: kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8, kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8_yuvs, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA). Mostly because I was trying to get a bi-planar buffer to easily extract the luma plane. But it didn't eliminate the aliasing. See the screenshot showing a Metal debug window that shows the luma values falling on very discreet numbers.

I wonder if it's a limitation of the source being 8-bits per channel. But then again, why would the ProRes 422 recording of it (same 8-bit signal) be smooth!? Maybe there's some additional smoothing going on in the encoding?

How are you getting your textures from AVPlayer? Can you log both yours and AVPlayer's textures and pixel buffers and post them?

Thanks for looking into this @GordonChilds. I updated the question with additional context about how I configure and retrieve the buffers, and logged both buffers and textures. If there is anything else that would be helpful please let me know.

Wait a sec. Where is the AVPlayer video coming from?

@GordonChilds, it's a local video file recorded with Quicktime in ProRes 422, using the same USB/UVC camera input that I'm using for AVCaptureDevice. I'm not sure I understood your question.

That answers the question! ProRes 422 is a 10bit per component format, so AVPlayer's 32bit usage may be an implementation detail. See instead if you can configure your video output to use kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange or the 420 version.
Your AVCaptureDevice needs to be configured for this too, maybe something you've already done when creating the ProRes 422 file? It would be good to include AVCaptureDevice.formats. More ProRes capture info here:   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3104-recording-video-in-apple-prores

I did configure the capture device to use kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange (422 not available). Mostly because I was trying to get a bi-planar buffer to easily extract the luma plane. But it didn't eliminate the aliasing. I'm attaching another screenshot showing a Metal debug window that shows the luma values falling on very discreet numbers. I wonder if it's just a limitation of the source being 8-bits per channel. But then again, why would the ProRes 422 recording of it be smooth!? Maybe there's some additional smoothing going on in the encoding?

So there's no 10bit format available on your capture device?

I'm testing on several different devices. The UVC one lists "offers" YpCbCr and 32BGRA options, but I think it's all 8-bit. I'm also testing with a BlackMagic UltraStudio Recorder 3G, which does support 10-bit/channel input, but I still see some artifacts with that. I'm starting to think that I'm gonna have to live with some level of discontinuity. But I'm still puzzled by why the video file looks so smooth when it was captured from the same signal.

You need to be able to capture 10 bit components. It's not clear how you're creating the ProRes video files if you can't configure the device to do this. Do you have some runnable code you can share?

I'll try to upload a runnable POC over the weekend. I'm creating the video files completely outside of the app: I just used Quicktime to record the camera input and saved it as a ProRes file. The file format is independent of the bit depth of the original signal. There is probably some softening of the image happening when transcoding it for saving, and ProRes can reproduce the smother image.

What device are you testing on?

I'm testing on an M1 MacBook Pro 15" and on an M1 iPad Pro. The screenshots attached above are all on the Mac.

You've configured AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to use kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, a 32bit format, and AVPlayer to use kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat, a 128 bit format. That 4x increase in component resolution is probably what is giving AVPlayer the smoother histogram.
Try configuring AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to use kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat. If you're lucky it will work.
Hopefully AVCaptureVideoDataOutput's availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes will report that 128 RGBA float is supported.
As a datapoint my mac doesn't claim to support it, but I don't think have mentioned which platform you're using.

Thanks. I did try configuring AVCaptureVideoDataOuput with the kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat pixel format but got the same result. I initially thought it could be compression artifacts but the video file is captured from the same video source. Analyzing the texture pixel-by-pixel I can clearly see the RGB values jump discretely in narrow "bands", instead of smooth float values.Resizing the frame first with something like CILanczosScaleTransform helps clear it up (as does blurring).

Just added a screenshot showing a kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat texture with several pixels having the exact same float values.
